# Pig :: Get MAX value from the COUNTs of a groups

Tags: apache-pig, digital-signature

I have a file Bank name, location and few other fields too. I want to find out the bank with maximum branches.

```
A = LOAD 'bank.txt';
B = GROUP A by $0;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE COUNT($1);
```

I go the Bank wise counts. Now I am stuck how to refer C to get the bank with MAX branches.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are grouping by Bank,you will have to generate the grouping and count the field that represents the branch,then order by the count desc and get the top row.

```
A = LOAD 'bank.txt';
B = GROUP A by $0;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE group as Bank,COUNT(B.Branches_Field) cnt;
D = ORDER C BY cnt DESC;
E = LIMIT D 1;
DUMP E;
```